# What is the public/manifest.json file really doing in a Vue app generated by Vue CLI 3.0?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli, manifest.json

When you generate an app with Vue CLI 3.0, and select PWA support. It generates a `public/manifest.json` file. However, these settings are not used in the meta tags, for example changing the theme color in the `manifest.json` file will not change the `<meta name="theme-color" ...>` tag.

To configure this you have to follow the readme of the `@vue/cli-plugin-pwa` and add the options in the `vue.config.js` file.

So what is the `manifest.json` file for?

Answer (score 6):

Basically, you've just initialised a fresh Vue progressive web app (PWA), so the `manifest.json` is potentially required for progressive web apps, `manifest.json` gives you the ability to control how your app could behave when a user expect to see an app (Mobile device's home screen), for example, add a splash screen to your app when the user gets access to your app through the mobile, configure the push notification sender_id etc ...

If you want to know more about Manifest, please check [Web app manifest](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/).